# Importing text file with varying number of columns in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pipe-delimited file with varying numbers of columns, like this:

```
id|name|attribute|extraattribute
1|alvin|cool|funny
2|bob|tall
3|cindy|smart|funny
```

I'm trying to find an elegant way to import this into a dataframe using pyspark.  I could try to fix the files to add a trailing | when the last column is missing (only the last column can be missing), but would love to find a solution that didn't involve changing the input files.

Comment: One option could be to read it in as one large column, adding a `|` at the end when appropriate, then split into columns as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964554/how-to-split-column-into-multiple-rows-with-pipe-as-separator).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method [`csv`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) in the module `pyspark.sql.readwriter` and set `mode="PERMISSIVE"`:

```python
df = sqlCtx.read.csv("/path/to/file.txt", sep="|", mode="PERMISSIVE", header=True)
df.show(truncate=False)
#+---+-----+---------+--------------+
#|id |name |attribute|extraattribute|
#+---+-----+---------+--------------+
#|1  |alvin|cool     |funny         |
#|2  |bob  |tall     |null          |
#|3  |cindy|smart    |funny         |
#+---+-----+---------+--------------+
```

From the docs:

> PERMISSIVE : sets other fields to null when it meets a corrupted
>   record.
>
> When a schema is set by user, it sets null for extra fields.

This is much easier than [what I originally suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158696/importing-text-file-with-varying-number-of-columns-in-spark/50159247#comment87335425_50158696).

Comment: This ignores last column if it contains null in first row.