# Read CSV file with variable number of commas as a data frame in PYSPARK

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a comma separated file, with no header, with different number of items in each line separated by a comma, such as:

```python
a, x1, x2  
b, x3, x4, x5  
c, x6, x7, x8, x9
```

The first line contains only 3 items, subsequent lines contain more, so it seems the number of columns is inferred from first line only, so it skips whatever after 3rd comma in other lines and data is lost.

```python
spark = init_spark()
df= spark.read.csv(filename)
print (df.take(3))
```

I get:

```python
[Row(_c0='a', _c1=' x1', _c2=' x2'),  
Row(_c0='b', _c1=' x3', _c2=' x4'),   
Row(_c0='c', _c1=' x6', _c2=' x7')]
```

mode="PERMISSIVE" in the module pyspark.sql.readwriter
doesn't solve the problem, may be because there is no header

Comment: You could read it in as a single column and then use map to expand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing text file with varying number of columns in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158696/importing-text-file-with-varying-number-of-columns-in-spark)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming max no of col or comma separated values known
And given the file a.csv

```
col_a,col_b,col_c,col_d,col_e
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,e
1,a,b
```

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("col_a", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col_b", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col_c", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col_d", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col_e", StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.read.csv("a.csv",header=True,schema=schema)

df.show()
```

which results

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|col_e|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    1|    2|    3|    4|    5|
|    1|    2|    3|    e| null|
|    1|    a|    b| null| null|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: For me, that causes a malformed error for all rows that don't have the full number of commas (in this case, 4 commas)

Comment: is it? i ran it with my local pyspark 2.4.4 it didnt show any errors.

Comment: One difference is that I have `header=False`. I'm using 2.4.3

Comment: Through testing I just found that the main problem was that I am explicitly specifying mode='FAILFAST'