# Converting RDD into Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, rdd

I am new in spark/scala.
I have a created below RDD by loading data from multiple paths. Now i want to create dataframe from same for further operations.
below should be the schema of dataframe

```
schema[UserId, EntityId, WebSessionId, ProductId]

rdd.foreach(println)

545456,5615615,DIKFH6545614561456,PR5454564656445454
875643,5485254,JHDSFJD543514KJKJ4
545456,5615615,DIKFH6545614561456,PR5454564656445454
545456,5615615,DIKFH6545614561456,PR5454564656445454
545456,5615615,DIKFH6545614561456,PR54545DSKJD541054
264264,3254564,MNXZCBMNABC5645SAD,PR5142545564542515
732543,8765984,UJHSG4240323545144
564574,6276832,KJDXSGFJFS2545DSAS
```

Will anyone please help me....!!!

I have tried same by defining schema class and mapping same against rdd but getting error

> "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :3"

Comment: You seem to have 3 elements in some rows and 4 in others. That should be the reason behind the exception.

Comment: Yes right..!!!  but I am looking for way out of this

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158696/importing-text-file-with-varying-number-of-columns-in-spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you treat your columns as String you can create with the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val rdd : RDD[Row] = ???

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, StructType(Seq(
  StructField("userId", StringType, false),
  StructField("EntityId", StringType, false),
  StructField("WebSessionId", StringType, false),
  StructField("ProductId", StringType, true))))
```

Note that you must "map" your RDD to a RDD[Row] for the compiler to allow to use the "createDataFrame" method. For the missing fields you can declare the columns as nullable in the DataFrame  Schema.

In your example you are using the RDD method *spark.sparkContext.textFile()*. This method returns a RDD[String] that means that each element of your RDD is a line. But, you need a RDD[Row]. So you need to split your string by commas like:

```
val list = 
 List("545456,5615615,DIKFH6545614561456,PR5454564656445454",
   "875643,5485254,JHDSFJD543514KJKJ4", 
   "545456,5615615,DIKFH6545614561456,PR5454564656445454", 
   "545456,5615615,DIKFH6545614561456,PR5454564656445454", 
   "545456,5615615,DIKFH6545614561456,PR54545DSKJD541054", 
   "264264,3254564,MNXZCBMNABC5645SAD,PR5142545564542515", 
"732543,8765984,UJHSG4240323545144","564574,6276832,KJDXSGFJFS2545DSAS")


val FilterReadClicks = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list)

val rows: RDD[Row] = FilterReadClicks.map(line => line.split(",")).map { arr =>
  val array = Row.fromSeq(arr.foldLeft(List[Any]())((a, b) => b :: a))
  if(array.length == 4) 
    array
  else Row.fromSeq(array.toSeq.:+(""))
}

rows.foreach(el => println(el.toSeq))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, StructType(Seq(
  StructField("userId", StringType, false),
  StructField("EntityId", StringType, false),
  StructField("WebSessionId", StringType, false),
  StructField("ProductId", StringType, true))))

df.show()

+------------------+------------------+------------+---------+
|            userId|          EntityId|WebSessionId|ProductId|
+------------------+------------------+------------+---------+
|PR5454564656445454|DIKFH6545614561456|     5615615|   545456|
|JHDSFJD543514KJKJ4|           5485254|      875643|         |
|PR5454564656445454|DIKFH6545614561456|     5615615|   545456|
|PR5454564656445454|DIKFH6545614561456|     5615615|   545456|
|PR54545DSKJD541054|DIKFH6545614561456|     5615615|   545456|
|PR5142545564542515|MNXZCBMNABC5645SAD|     3254564|   264264|
|UJHSG4240323545144|           8765984|      732543|         |
|KJDXSGFJFS2545DSAS|           6276832|      564574|         |
+------------------+------------------+------------+---------+
```

With rows rdd you will be able to create the dataframe.

Comment: Hi, It is giving error as error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:

Comment: edit your question an add your RDD code to see what it´s happening.

Comment: val ReadClicks = c.textFile(FlumePath)     \\here flume path is containing multiple data sources



val FilterReadClicks  = ReadClicks.filter(x => ((!x.isEmpty) && (x != null) && (x.lenght >3)))



\\now here I am trying for coversion of RDD into dataframe



val df = spark.createDataframe(FilterReadClicks, StructType(Seq(StructField("userId", StringType, false),StructField("EntityId", StringType, false),StructField("WebSessionId", StringType, false),StructField("ProductId", StringType, true))))

Comment: How can I create RDD[Row] or is there any way out to convert RDD[String] into RDD[Row]

Comment: Thank you for updates...but seems no luck..!! I have added suggested code