# Advanced join two dataframe spark scala

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have to join two Dataframes.

Sample:
Dataframe1 looks like this

```
df1_col1      df1_col2
   a            ex1
   b            ex4
   c            ex2
   d            ex6
   e            ex3
```

Dataframe2

```
df2_col1      df2_col2
   1           a,b,c
   2           d,c,e
   3           a,e,c
```

In result Dataframe I would like to get result like this

```
res_col1      res_col2       res_col3
    a           ex1             1
    a           ex1             3
    b           ex4             1
    c           ex2             1
    c           ex2             2
    c           ex2             3
    d           ex6             2
    e           ex3             2
    e           ex3             3
```

What will be the best way to achieve this join?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the code below

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a","ex1"),("b","ex4"),("c","ex2"),("d","ex6"),("e","ex3")))
val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(List(("1","a,b,c"),("2","d,c,e")))).toDF
df2.withColumn("df2_col2_explode", explode(split($"_2", ","))).select($"_1".as("df2_col1"),$"df2_col2_explode").join(df1.select($"_1".as("df1_col1"),$"_2".as("df1_col2")), $"df1_col1"===$"df2_col2_explode","inner").show
```

You just need to split the values and generate multiple rows by exploding it and then join with the other dataframe.

You can refer this link, [How to split pipe-separated column into multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964554/how-to-split-pipe-separated-column-into-multiple-rows)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I used spark sql for this join. I posted my solution below.

Comment: @Sc0rpion You'r performing join on Dataframe and RDD is it possble to perform?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to use higher level of abstractions provided over rdd than using rdd itself. Be it a sql, dataframe or datasets, it boils down to an RDD.

Answer (score 1):

I used spark sql for this join, here is a part of code;

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_v_df1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_v_df2")
val df_result = spark.sql("""select 
                    |   b.df1_col1 as res_col1, 
                    |   b.df1_col2 as res_col2, 
                    |   a.df2_col1 as res_col3  
                    |   from (select df2_col1, exp_col 
                    |         from temp_v_df2 
                    |        lateral view explode(split(df2_col2,",")) dummy as exp_col) a
                    |   join temp_v_df1 b on a.exp_col = b.df1_col1""".stripMargin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used spark scala data frame to achieve your desire output.

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a","ex1"),("b","ex4"),("c","ex2"),("d","ex6"),("e","ex3"))).toDF("df1_col1","df1_col2") 

val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,("a,b,c")),(2,("d,c,e")),(3,("a,e,c")))).toDF("df2_col1","df2_col2") 

df2.withColumn("_tmp", explode(split($"df2_col2", "\\,"))).as("temp").join (df1,$"temp._tmp"===df1("df1_col1"),"inner").drop("_tmp","df2_col2").show
```

> Desire Output

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|df2_col1|df1_col1|df1_col2|
+--------+--------+--------+
|       2|       e|     ex3|
|       3|       e|     ex3|
|       2|       d|     ex6|
|       1|       c|     ex2|
|       2|       c|     ex2|
|       3|       c|     ex2|
|       1|       b|     ex4|
|       1|       a|     ex1|
|       3|       a|     ex1|
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Rename the Column according to your requirement.

**Here the screenshot of running code**

[image]
**Happy Hadoooooooooooooooppppppppppppppppppp**